# how do I convert classic reactjs to hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to covert the following to hooks, but however I am getting some issues to translate this line `this.fetchPlaces = debounce(this.fetchPlaces, 200);`  what is the exact match for hooks?

````
state = {
    q: '',
    places: [],
}
fetchPlaces(q) {
    get(`http://www.example.com/places/`, {
        params: {q}
    }).then(response => {
        this.setState({places: response.data.places});
    });
}
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.fetchPlaces = debounce(this.fetchPlaces, 200);
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to go through React Hooks' [official guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), by the end of the guide lies a full example of how to use react hooks.

You should use useState hook to manage states and use useEffect hook to load data from network.

```
const Foo = () =>{
   // all hooks should be used in top level of the function component.
   // orders matter.
   // https://www.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level
   const [q, setQ] = useState(''); // use hooks to declare q
   const [places, setPlaces] = useState([]); // use hooks to declare places

   // load data from network after React Nodes are rendered
   useEffect(()=>{
      get(`http://www.example.com/places/`, {
        params: {q}
      }).then(response => {
        setPlaces(response.data.places); // call setPlaces to set state
      });
   }
   ,[1]);  // passing a constant to the second Array parameter to strict the hook be called only for once, if left undefined, useEffect will be called after every render.
   return // React Nodes
}
```

I've used react hooks for a while, you can checkout my full example here.
https://github.com/ShinChven/bootcamp/blob/master/console/src/pages/Admin/Users/Users.tsx

I do not see why you should call network with debounce, but here's a post for that.
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/debounce-and-throttle-in-react-with-hooks/

Answer (score 0):

```
const fetchPlaces = (q) => {
    get(`http://www.example.com/places/`, {
        params: {q}
    }).then(response => {
        setPlaces(response.data.places);
    });
}

const deboucedFetchPlaces = debounce(fetchPlaces, 200)
```

Then in your code you can call `deboucedFetchPlaces`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
const fetchMore = _.debounce(fetchPlaces, 500);

fetchPlaces(q) {
    get(`http://www.example.com/places/`, {
        params: {q}
    }).then(response => {
        this.setState({places: response.data.places});
    });
}

fetchMore();
```